# Adding a new column to numpy array changes the initial array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to numpy library. and the problem I am facing is this.
My initial array is this:

```
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

and when I add a column using **resize** function :

```
arr.resize(4,2)
```

it changes to this :

```
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

but what I want something like this:

```
[[1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

Is there a way to do this ? I tried finding the answer to this but couldn't. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Read the resize docs carefully

Comment: @hpaulj I did and now I know why resize is working like this but I just want to add a new column or new row without changing the my previous array. How to do this using numpy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a solution for you, hope it helps!

```
len = np.ones((4,1))

array([[1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.]])

len0 = np.zeros((4,1))

array([[0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.]])
```

Using concatenate you can achieve your goal:

```
np.concatenate((len,len0),axis=1)

array([[1., 0.],
   [1., 0.],
   [1., 0.],
   [1., 0.]])
```

Happy learning!

Comment: This solution helps and  I also used np.row_stack and np.column_stack for adding rows and cols. that too solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Was unaware of those functions! Thanks for the info

Comment: `np.concatenate` is the underlying function for all of the `stack` functions.  Knowing how to use it is a good thing.